# ¿Cómo ordenar un arreglo de objetos por fecha?

Tags: javascript, json, array, object

Buen día amigos,

supongamos que tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
var array = [
         {  fechas:"29-10",
            registros:52
         },
         {
            fechas:"27-10",
            registros:9
          },
         {
            fechas:"26-10",
            registros:8
         },
         {
            fechas:"25-10",
            registros:5
         }
];
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero que necesito es que me muestre los objetos en orden de fecha es decir de la siguiente manera:

```
 var array = [
         {
           fechas: "25-10", 
           registros: 5
         },
         {
           fechas: "26-10", 
           registros: 8
         },
         {
           fechas: "27-10", 
           registros: 9
         },
         {
           fechas: "29-10", 
           registros: 52
         } 
];
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde una función de js?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La siguiente forma te sirve para ese conjunto de datos específico, pero no es muy útil para otros conjuntos, ni si quiera ordena por su valor numérico, lo hace por el valor del string.

```js
var array = [
     {  fechas:"29-10",
        registros:52
     },
     {
        fechas:"27-10",
        registros:9
      },
     {
        fechas:"26-10",
        registros:8
     },
     {
        fechas:"25-10",
        registros:5
     }
];
console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a.fechas > b.fechas));
```

Pero, está esta otra solución, que creo te podría servir más, ya que ordena por tiempo realmente, desde año hasta milisegundos si quieres, el único incoveniente es que tu conjunto de datos no tiene el año, pero aún así, le puedes agregar cualquier año y te los va a seguir ordenando correctamente.

Te dejo un poco de documentación:

- [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)
- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)

```js
var array = [
         {  fechas:"2019-10-29",
            registros:52
         },
         {
            fechas:"2017-10-27",
            registros:9
          },
         {
            fechas:"2019-10-26",
            registros:8
         },
         {
            fechas:"2018-10-25",
            registros:5
         },
         {
            fechas:"2017-1-15",
            registros:5
         }
];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fechas).getTime() > new Date(b.fechas).getTime()));
```

Comment: muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba!

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar por fecha primero debes tener las fechas en tipo [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) para que JavaScript las pueda ordenar, de lo contrario las ordenarás como string, podrías crear una funcion que retorne la fecha dependiendo el formato que le ingreses:

```
/*
  Puede recibir fechas en formato: "dd-mm" (supone año actual) o "dd-mm-aaaa"
  (Esta función esta ajustada a las fechas que tienes)
*/
function convertirFecha (fechaString) {
  var fechaSp = fechaString.split("-");
  var anio = new Date().getFullYear();
  if (fechaSp.length == 3) {
    anio = fechaSp[2];
  }
  var mes = fechaSp[1] - 1;
  var dia = fechaSp[0];

  return new Date(anio, mes, dia);
}
```

**Para ordenar:**
Una vez teniendo la función que crea las fechas dependiendo el formato que tengas, puedes usar la función [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) de la siguiente forma:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) { 
  return convertirFecha(a.fechas) - convertirFecha(b.fechas); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Con momentjs podría ser así:

```js
//const moment = require("moment")

let array = [
  { fechas: "29-10", registros: 52 },
  {
    fechas: "27-10",
    registros: 9
  },
  {
    fechas: "26-10",
    registros: 8
  },
  {
    fechas: "25-10",
    registros: 5
  }
];


// with moment js
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => moment(a.fechas, "DD-MM").unix() - moment(b.fechas, "DD-MM").unix());
console.log("With moment js: \n", sortedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Será últi para el OP y otros que encuentren la pregunta más adelante si incluyes una explicación sobre el código y sobre qué hace la biblioteca `moment`.