# ordenar mi array en orden alfabetico en ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Guardo la lista de mi API en el estado que cree, llamado "data". cuando hago el map me trae la data. Pero quiero que me la traiga en orden alfabético. Estaba pensando en usar sort en mi useEffect en la const "ordenalpha". Pero no me funciona.

```javascript
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:3001/apianimals")
          .then((res) => {
    
        const ordenalpha = res.data.sort(a, b) => {
         var n = a.toLocaleLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLocaleLowerCase());
        }
           setData(ordenalpha);
            console.log(res.data, "heree");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        },[]);
```

Comment: Cuando dices "pero no me funciona" ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona? ¿Te refieres al `console.log(res.data, "heree")`? ¿no ves los datos ordenados en ese log? Por favor elabora un poco más.

Comment: Otra cosa que puede ser de ayuda para la comunidad, ¿Qué tipo de datos estas recibiendo en `res.data`? ¿Un arreglo de elementos tipo `string`? Si pudieras agregar ese dato a la pregunta, lo que muestra el `console.log(res.data)`

Comment: la funcion ordenalpha no me funciona

Comment: ¿Puedes mostramos que hay en `res.data`? `console.log(res.data)`

Comment: ya lo resolvi. ahora trato de ordenarlos por fecha pero tengo problemas

Comment: [ordenar por fechas JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209857/cómo-ordenar-un-arreglo-de-objetos-por-fecha), Saludos